# on() event input in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I implemented a ready script (found some time ago in this forum) to my program, in short, it changes the name of the class in the input object and adds the ability to clear it when something is written or changed, but sometimes value is stored using the post method and after the page reboots, the function is not immediately invoked.

```js
function tog(v) {
  return v ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
}

$(document).on('input', '.clearable', function() {
  $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
}).on('mousemove', '.x', function(e) {
  $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth - 18 < e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');
}).on('touchstart click', '.onX', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('').change();
});
```

```html
<input name="producent_new" type="text" class="clearable" value="$_POST[producent_new]"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to handle your issue is to trigger the input event for each of the relevant elements on document load, so the handler is executed and it sets the state that you'd expect.

Just add this to your script...

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    $(".clearable").trigger("input");
});
```

Comment: Wow, I thought about such a solution but my knowledge in jq is definitely too small, thank you very much <3